# How can I find the following convolution sum?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

$$ h[n]= \left( \frac{8}{9} \right) ^n u[n-3] $$

And the function is:
$$x[n] =
           \begin{cases}
                      2 &         \text{if } 0 \leq n \leq9, \\                               
                      0 &         \text{ else}.
           \end{cases}$$

In order to find the convolution sum $y[n]=x[n]*h[n]$:

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}{x[k]\cdot h[n-k]}$$

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} {x[k]\cdot \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^k\cdot u[n-3-k]}$$

How do I proceed from here? I know that $x[n]=0 \ \text{for} \ k<0 \ \text{and} \  k>9$

But is $h[n]$ 0 for $n>k−3$?

In essence, how do I evaluate a finite sum for these conditions if they are correct?

Any help would be appreciated as this is my first time taking signals and systems...

Comment: A first step would be to write the convolution sum correctly. On the left you have $y[n]$ but on the right you have a sequence depending on the index $k$ (with $n$ just being the summation index).

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: The step function $u \left[ n - 3 \right]$ and the domain of $x \left[ n \right]$, $0 \neq x \neq 9$ give you the chance to calculate the $k$ index values that will not result in zero of the convolution sum (in essence, the $k$ values for which your two signals $x \left[ k \right]$ and $h \left[ k \right]$ will overlap). From there you can drop the unit step function and perform the sum.

Comment: You should sum over $k$, not over $n$. And you got the formula for $h[n-k]$ wrong.

Comment: "But is h[n] 0 for n>k−3?" ?  I think you meant is h[n-k] 0 ?   h[n] is never zero for n>3.

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to review my concepts... Thanks, everyone!